# Return continuous result from a single function call

Tags: python, events, data-structures, asynchronous

I have got stuck with a problem.
It goes like this,
A function returns a single result normally. What I want is it to return continuous streams of result for a certain time frame(optional).

Is it feasible for a function to repeatedly return results for a single function call?

While browsing through the net I did come across gevent and threading. Will it work if so any heads up how to solve it?

I just need to call the function carry out the work and return results immediately after every task is completed.

Comment: Can you reprogram the function as a [generator](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/python_programming/python_ch18.html)?

Comment: I'm not sure if i understood the question completely. Are you looking for some sort of non-blocking call to a function and be notified when function has something interesting to let the caller know?

Comment: Read about [`yield`](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#yield) and [coroutines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coroutine).

Comment: What are you doing with the results?

Answer (score 2):

Why you need this is not specified in the question, so it is hard to know what you need, but I will give you a general idea, and code too.

You could return in that way: `return var1, var2, var3` (but that's not what you need I think)

You have multiple options: either blocking or non-blocking. Blocking means your code will no longer execute while you are calling the function. Non-blocking means that it will run in parallel. You should also know that you will definitely need to modify the code calling that function.

That's if you want it in a thread (non-blocking):

```
def your_function(callback):
    # This is a function defined inside of it, just for convenience, it can be any function.
    def what_it_is_doing(callback):
        import time
        total = 0
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
            total += 1
            # Here it is a callback function, but if you are using a
            # GUI application (not only) for example (wx, Qt, GTK, ...) they usually have
            # events/signals, you should be using this system.
            callback(time_spent=total)

    import thread
    thread.start_new_thread(what_it_is_doing, tuple(callback))

# The way you would use it:
def what_I_want_to_do_with_each_bit_of_result(time_spent):
    print "Time is:", time_spent

your_function(what_I_want_to_do_with_each_bit_of_result)
# Continue your code normally
```

The other option (blocking) involves a special kind of functions `generators` which are technically treated as iterators. So you define it as a function and acts as an iterator. That's an example, using the same dummy function than the other one:

```
def my_generator():
    import time
    total = 0
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        total += 1
        yield total

# And here's how you use it:
# You need it to be in a loop !!
for time_spent in my_generator():
    print "Time spent is:", time_spent

# Or, you could use it that way, and call .next() manually:
my_gen = my_generator()
# When you need something from it:
time_spent = my_gen.next()
```

**Note** that in the second example, the code would make no sense because it is not really called at 1 second intervals, because there's the other code running each time it `yield`s something or `.next` is called, and that may take time. But I hope you got the point.

Again, it depends on what you are doing, if the app you are using has an "event" framework or similar you would need to use that, if you need it blocking/non-blocking, if time is important, how your calling code should manipulate the result...

Answer (score 0):

Your gevent and threading are on the right track, because a function does what it is programmed to do, either accepting 1 var at a time or taking a set and returning either a set or a var. The function has to be called to return either result, and the continuous stream of processing is probably taking place already or else you are asking about a loop over a kernel pointer or something similar, which you are not, so ...

So, your **calling code which encapsulates your function** is important, the function, any function, eg, even a true/false boolean function only executes until it is done with its vars, so there muse be a calling function which listens indefinitely in your case. If it doesn't exist you should write one ;)

Calling code which encapsulates is certainly very important.

Folks aren't going to have enough info to help much, except in the super generic sense that we can tell you that you are or should be within in some framework's event loop, or other code's loop of some form already- and that is what you want to be listening to/ preparing data for.

I like "functional programming's," "map function," for this sort of thing. I think. I can't comment at my rep level or I would restrict my speculation to that. :)

To get a better answer from another person post some example code and reveal your API if possible.